# Swift access closure members programmatically

Tags: swift, promisekit

I am building a Swift app and using PromiseKit to make the async features more readable.

From the [PromiseKit docs](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit/blob/master/Documentation/GettingStarted.md#when), I can see that it supports multiple concurrent promises. I wrote some code as follows to generate promises in a for loop then wait for them all to get fulfilled.

```
for index in 0...100 {
    let urlString = "https://someurl.com/item/\(index)"
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
    requestPromises += [URLSession.shared.dataTask(.promise, with: url).validate()]
}

firstly {
    when(fulfilled: requestPromises)
}.done {
    // process results
}
```

The example in the docs shows to write the promise as:

```
firstly {
    when(fulfilled: operation1(), operation2())
}.done { result1, result2 in
    //…
}
```

My problem is I don't want to write out result1, result2, ... result100. Is there a way to programmatically access the results?

Comment: I had a quick run through the extend docs and both the [`Timeout` example](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit/blob/master/Documentation/CommonPatterns.md#timeout) and [`when` Variants](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit/blob/master/Documentation/GettingStarted.md#when-variants) documentation seem to show that you can use and array of promises, assuming they return the same generic return

Comment: @rhlsthrm show us function done declaration

Comment: @MadProgrammer so I can declare the `done` argument as an array and loop through it?

Comment: In theory (not used PromiseKit for a while), yes, the results “should” be passed to done and should be in the same order

Comment: I tried to play around it and I couldn't find a way to achieve it... Means that I had to type `result1, result2 ... result100 in`

Comment: @AhmadF it worked for me the way MadProgrammer specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this the following way (thanks @MadProgrammer):

```
for index in 0...100 {
    let urlString = "https://someurl.com/item/\(index)"
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
    requestPromises += [URLSession.shared.dataTask(.promise, with: url).validate()]
}

firstly {
    when(fulfilled: requestPromises)
}.done { results in
    // process results
}
```

Comment: Ok, so what you should do is to pass only one parameter `results` which refers to the result of each promise, correct?

Comment: I am getting: `Contextual type for closure argument list expects 1 argument, which cannot be implicitly ignored`